# How to use in retrofit 1.9 in a property property?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

How do I use retrofit in the `( "Name": "AccountManager")` property

```
[  {
    "ID": 3065,
    "UserName": "test",
    "Email": "test",
    "Password": "test",
    "SkypeID": "test",
    "GoogleHangout": "test",
    "Inactive": false,
    "HasHoursRegistered": false,
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "EditedBy": null,
    "WebRole": null,
    "ProjectsDtos": null,
    "RegHoursDtos": null,
    "CustomersDtos": null,
    "RolesDtos": \[
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "AccountManager",
        "Prices": null,
        "Users": null,
        "UsersRolesProjects": null
      }
    \],
    "UsersRolesProjectsDtos": null
  }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object to handle the response, inside this object, you need a list of object `RolesDtos` (because is an array of objects)

```
public class RolesDtos{
  int ID;
  String Name;    
  String prices;
  String Users;
  ...
  setters and getters
}

public class ResponseObject{
  int ID;
  String userName;    
  String email;
  String password;
  String skypeId;
  ...
  List<RolesDtos> rolesDtos; // <- here 
  ...
  setters and getters
}
```

To get the `"Name": "AccountManager"`you have to do something like:

```
ResponseObject responseObject = new ResponseObject();
responseObject.getRolesDtos().get(0).getName();
```

`get(0)` is the position of the array, so, you must to iterate the array. Now in the request you have to do something like this:

```
@GET("url")
Call<ResponseObject> theRequest(...)
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

```
       How i can set here the  "Name": "AccountManager" property?  
 User user = getItem(position);


                if (user != null) {
                TextView tvUserId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_id);
                TextView tvUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
                TextView tvEmail=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.email);
                TextView tvRole=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.userRole);

                tvUserId.setText( Integer.toString(user.ID));
                tvUserName.setText(user.UserName);
                tvEmail.setText(user.Email);
              //  tvRole.setText(user.getRolesDtos().toArray(1));
```